# Unlock question

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, locked-posts

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57783601/1630171) was locked by a moderator due to a significant amount of edits and rollbacks, which apparently made it look like an edit/rollback war.

That isn't what was happening, though. The OP did most of the edits and rollbacks by themselves, presumably because at that point they didn't understand how editing works on Stack Overflow.

I asked them to stop that in a comment, and they did (after which I deleted my now obsolete comment).

Bottom line: the issue had already been resolved amicably before a moderator stepped in, so I'd request unlocking the question again.

Comment: You might want to flag this question for moderator attention and explain the issue in the flag text.

Comment: @BDL Good point. I should've thought of that. Thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks, I've unlocked the question.